# how to create separate superuser for diffrent login in django

Tags: python, django

Can i created a separate login using login authentication ? i m creating a super user which is used in both site user site and django admin site .. how to limit this access to separate login ?

```
my login template
{% block base%}
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
          <button type="submit">
      <i class="spinner"></i>
      <span class="state">Log in</span>
    </button>

  </form>
{% endblock %}

my login url 

 url(r'^login$',auth_views.login,{'template_name':'login.html'},name='login'),
```

Comment: Can you please improve your question by fixing the grammar a bit and adding more details to the question?

Comment: Please elaborate your question more.

Comment: From what I'm able to comprehend, what you should do is:  write user login functionality by yourself (and not touch the django-admin login setup. leave it for admin stuff). Django provides a lot of utility methods to create a custom login view.

Comment: can i use a django buid in authentication for seperate login page ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django+login).

Comment: but how can i specify ?  url(r'^login$',auth_views.login,{'template_name':'login.html'},name='login'), this is my url